# How to copy xml file contents from one xml file to another xml file using Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell, iis, powershell-ise, powershell-cmdlet

```
From below web.config file I want to copy the contents to another config file:
 <?xml version="1.0"?>     
     <configSections>...</configSections>   
    <system.webserver>...</system.webserver> 
        <configuration>  
                <appSettings>
                    <add key="ConnectionString" value=" Data Source=192.168.1.19;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=Demo;Persist Security Info=True; User ID=sa;Password=powershell;Application Name=web;Connect Timeout=200; pooling='true'; Max Pool Size=200;"/>
                    <add key="ConnectionString1" value=" Data Source=192.168.1.19;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=Demo;Persist Security Info=True; User ID=sa;Password=powershell;Application Name=web;Connect Timeout=200; pooling='true'; Max Pool Size=200;"/>
                    <add key="ConnectionString2" value=" Data Source=192.168.1.19;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=Demo;Persist Security Info=True; User ID=sa;Password=powershell;Application Name=web;Connect Timeout=200; pooling='true'; Max Pool Size=200;"/>
                    <add key="key1" value ="value1"/>
                    <add key="key2" value ="value2"/>
                    <add key="key3" value ="value3"/>
                    <add key="key4" value ="value4"/>
                    .....<add key="key30" value ="value30"/>
                  </appSettings>
            </configuration>
```

Tags which are copied from above config file need to show as below Expected config file "web1.config" with following contents:

```
From above xml file I want to copy  only "ConnectionString,ConnectionString1,ConnectionString2" tags from <appSettings> parent tag as

<?xml version="1.0"?>
             <appSettings>
                    <add key="ConnectionString" value=" Data Source=192.168.1.19;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=Demo;Persist Security Info=True; User ID=sa;Password=powershell;Application Name=web;Connect Timeout=200; pooling='true'; Max Pool Size=200;"/>
                    <add key="ConnectionString1" value=" Data Source=192.168.1.19;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=Demo;Persist Security Info=True; User ID=sa;Password=powershell;Application Name=web;Connect Timeout=200; pooling='true'; Max Pool Size=200;"/>
                    <add key="ConnectionString2" value=" Data Source=192.168.1.19;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=Demo;Persist Security Info=True; User ID=sa;Password=powershell;Application Name=web;Connect Timeout=200; pooling='true'; Max Pool Size=200;"/>
            </appSettings>
            <settings>
            <add key="key1" value ="value1"/>
                    <add key="key2" value ="value2"/>
                    <add key="key3" value ="value3"/>
                    <add key="key4" value ="value4"/>
                    .....<add key="key30" value ="value30"/>
            </settings>
```

Answer (score 1):

The script retrieves the ConnectionString keys and values from the reference XML using a **regular expression** and adds it to the destination XML using **System.Xml.XmlDocument**.

```powershell
$referenceXMLPath = 'c:\test1.xml'
$destinationXMLPath = 'c:\test2.xml'

$referenceContent = (gc $referenceXMLPath -Raw)
$destinationContent = [xml](gc $referenceXMLPath -Raw)

foreach ($connectionString in [regex]::Matches($referenceContent, '<add key="(ConnectionString[^"]*).*value="([^"]*)'))
{
    $key = $connectionString.Groups[1].Value
    $value = $connectionString.Groups[2].Value

    $child = $destinationContent.CreateElement("add")

    $keyAttribute = $destinationContent.CreateAttribute("key")
    $keyAttribute.Value = $key
    $child.Attributes.Append($keyAttribute)

    $valueAttribute = $destinationContent.CreateAttribute("value")
    $valueAttribute.Value = $value
    $child.Attributes.Append($valueAttribute)

    $destinationContent.configuration.appSettings.AppendChild($child)

}

$destinationContent.Save($destinationXMLPath)
```

Comment: In my scenario destination file doesn't have.It should create in specified path given in script. Need to copy root tags from web.config to web1.config. and order of the appsettings should remain same in web1.config file as web.config file.

Comment: The order of the appsettings is not relevant in XML. What do you mean with copy root tags? You wrote 'From above xml file I want to copy  only "ConnectionString,ConnectionString1,ConnectionString2" tags from <appSettings>'. Do you mean you want to transform the reference xml to a new xml or do you want to copy only the connection strings from the reference to a destination?

Comment: Yes, to copy root tag of <appsettings> connectionstrings </appsettings> and the key,values from key1 to key30  to some root tag like <application>key, values from 1 to 30</application> to specified destination in code (destination xml file need to create dynamically)

Comment: @Praveen Can you post a COMPLETE sample (reference and the excpected result)

Comment: Please check. I have posted reference and expected result

Answer (score 0):

Reference config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>  
        <appSettings>
            <add key="ConnectionString" value=" Data Source=192.168.1.19;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=Demo;Persist Security Info=True; User ID=sa;Password=powershell;Application Name=web;Connect Timeout=200; pooling='true'; Max Pool Size=200;"/>
            <add key="ConnectionString1" value=" Data Source=192.168.1.19;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=Demo;Persist Security Info=True; User ID=sa;Password=powershell;Application Name=web;Connect Timeout=200; pooling='true'; Max Pool Size=200;"/>
            <add key="ConnectionString2" value=" Data Source=192.168.1.19;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=Demo;Persist Security Info=True; User ID=sa;Password=powershell;Application Name=web;Connect Timeout=200; pooling='true'; Max Pool Size=200;"/>
            <add key="key1" value ="value1"/>
            <add key="key2" value ="value2"/>
            <add key="key3" value ="value3"/>
            <add key="key4" value ="value4"/>
            .....<add key="key5" value ="value30"/>
          </appSettings>
    </configuration>
```

Expected config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
     <appSettings>
            <add key="ConnectionString" value=" Data Source=192.168.1.19;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=Demo;Persist Security Info=True; User ID=sa;Password=powershell;Application Name=web;Connect Timeout=200; pooling='true'; Max Pool Size=200;"/>
            <add key="ConnectionString1" value=" Data Source=192.168.1.19;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=Demo;Persist Security Info=True; User ID=sa;Password=powershell;Application Name=web;Connect Timeout=200; pooling='true'; Max Pool Size=200;"/>
            <add key="ConnectionString2" value=" Data Source=192.168.1.19;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=Demo;Persist Security Info=True; User ID=sa;Password=powershell;Application Name=web;Connect Timeout=200; pooling='true'; Max Pool Size=200;"/>
    </appSettings>
    <settings>
    <add key="key1" value ="value1"/>
            <add key="key2" value ="value2"/>
            <add key="key3" value ="value3"/>
            <add key="key4" value ="value4"/>
            .....<add key="key5" value ="value30"/>
    </settings>
```

Comment: there is no root element in the expected config?

Comment: Maybe just use my script as a reference and adapt it to your needs

Comment: Yes there no root element for expected config file